# dplyr mutate by row names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data and I am trying to run some very basic calculations based on row names. I basically want to add together `Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities` + `Capital Expenditures` from the row names using dplyr and just store them as a new row. The below code eventually does what I want but its quite bulky and I am trying to create it in one pipe function not two.

```
CFt <- as.data.frame(t(CF))
 library(dplyr)
 FCF <- NULL
 FCF <- CFt %>%
  select(`Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities`, `Capital Expenditures`)

 FCF <- FCF %>% 
   rownames_to_column('Firms') %>%
   mutate(FCF = `Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities` + `Capital Expenditures`) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('Firms') %>%
   t()
```

Data:

```
CF <- structure(list(GE2017 = c(-5786000, 7359000, 5568000, 1551000, 
987000, 747000, NA, 10426000, -7371000, NA, 5891000, 2322000, 
-8650000, NA, -8952000, 1006000, -19146000, 891000, -5507000), 
    GE2016 = c(8831000, 7139000, -19373000, 1514000, 3034000, 
    -1389000, NA, -244000, -7199000, NA, -10250000, 49202000, 
    -8806000, NA, -58411000, -485000, -89131000, -1146000, -41319000
    ), GE2015 = c(-6126000, 6509000, 21411000, -52000, -1537000, 
    -314000, NA, 19891000, -7309000, NA, -5316000, 59488000, 
    -9295000, NA, -57546000, -8114000, -76054000, -3464000, -138000
    ), GE2014 = c(15233000, 6423000, 8788000, -1913000, 50000, 
    -872000, NA, 27709000, -7134000, NA, 406000, -5034000, -8852000, 
    NA, -30190000, 23304000, -16956000, -3492000, 2224000), GOOG2017 = c(12662000, 
    6899000, 8284000, -3768000, 1121000, NA, 3682000, 37091000, 
    -13184000, -19448000, 1419000, -31401000, NA, NA, -86000, 
    -3366000, -8298000, 405000, -2203000), GOOG2016 = c(19478000, 
    6100000, 7158000, -2578000, 333000, NA, 2420000, 36036000, 
    -10212000, -18229000, -1978000, -31165000, NA, NA, -1335000, 
    -3304000, -8332000, -170000, -3631000), GOOG2015 = c(16348000, 
    5024000, 5609000, -2094000, 246000, NA, 1618000, 26572000, 
    -9950000, -13635000, 75000, -23711000, NA, NA, -23000, -2422000, 
    -4225000, -434000, -1798000), GOOG2014 = c(14136000, 4601000, 
    3615000, -1641000, 261000, NA, 1461000, 23024000, -11014000, 
    -6222000, 628000, -21055000, NA, NA, -18000, -2069000, -2087000, 
    -433000, -551000), NVDA2018 = c(3047000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    NVDA2017 = c(1666000, 187000, 473000, -321000, 184000, -375000, 
    -167000, 1672000, -176000, -619000, -5000, -793000, -261000, 
    NA, 1315000, -24000, 291000, NA, 1170000), NVDA2016 = c(614000, 
    197000, 386000, -32000, -11000, 66000, -74000, 1175000, -86000, 
    -339000, 18000, -4e+05, -213000, 120000, 1315000, 4000, -676000, 
    NA, 99000), NVDA2015 = c(631000, 220000, 230000, -49000, 
    -27000, -95000, -32000, 906000, -122000, -625000, -1000, 
    -727000, -186000, 154000, 1315000, 12000, -834000, NA, -655000
    )), .Names = c("GE2017", "GE2016", "GE2015", "GE2014", "GOOG2017", 
"GOOG2016", "GOOG2015", "GOOG2014", "NVDA2018", "NVDA2017", "NVDA2016", 
"NVDA2015"), row.names = c("Net Income", "Depreciation", "Adjustments To Net Income", 
"Changes In Accounts Receivables", "Changes In Liabilities", 
"Changes In Inventories", "Changes In Other Operating Activities", 
"Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities", "Capital Expenditures", 
"Investments", "Other Cash flows from Investing Activities", 
"Total Cash Flows From Investing Activities", "Dividends Paid", 
"Sale Purchase of Stock", "Net Borrowings", "Other Cash Flows from Financing Activities", 
"Total Cash Flows From Financing Activities", "Effect Of Exchange Rate Changes", 
"Change In Cash and Cash Equivalents"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you need `colSums(CF[c( "Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities" , "Capital Expenditures" ),], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Or ` CF %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% filter(rn %in% c( "Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities" , "Capital Expenditures" )) %>% summarise_at(-1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Yes both work as I hoped! Just need to now store the newely created data under a row name as opposed to `CF$Colname`.

Comment: So, isn't it just to bind (getting lost with auto complete) the rows

Comment: Well, I am putting `rbind()` or `add_row()` at the end of the `dplyr` code you gave me but somehow its not storing the values in the `CF` data frame. (I can store the values outside of the pipe function and then use `rbind(x, y)` but just wondering if it could all be done in one pipe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use `bind_rows`, it will strip off the row names and assigns default row numbers.  So, we are using `rbind`

```
library(tidyverse)
CF %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
   filter(rn %in% c( "Total Cash Flow From Oprating Activities" , 
         "Capital Expenditures" )) %>% 
   summarise_at(-1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   `row.names<-`(., 'TotalCashFlowOPAc+CapitalExpend') %>% 
   rbind(CF, .)
```

Comment: Thanks, this now adds the variable to the end of the `CF`data frame.

Comment: However the calculations are different.

`x <- CF %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  filter(rn %in% c("Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities" , "Capital Expenditures")) %>% 
  summarise_at(-1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)


library(tidyverse)
xy <- CF %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  filter(rn %in% c( "Total Cash Flow From Oprating Activities" , 
                    "Capital Expenditures" )) %>% 
  summarise_at(-1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  `row.names<-`(., 'TotalCashFlowOPAc+CapitalExpend') %>% 
  rbind(CF, .)

tail(x, 1)
tail(xy, 1)`

Comment: Not sure why the first method you proposed made the correct calculations but the second method didn´t.

Comment: @user113156. I am getting the same values

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different solution than @akrun's

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

CF %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  filter(rn %in% c('Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities',
                   'Capital Expenditures')) %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarize_all(sum) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  column_to_rownames('rn') %>%
  rbind(., FCF = colSums(.))
```